# Is there any way to edit xero invoice after marked as paid using PHP SDK?

Tags: php, xero-api

right now I used PHP SDK to create/update invoices and also I used payments API to make as paid.

but in some cases I need to edit the order even after the invoice is marked as paid, I am not able to find the way how to do it.

Can anyone guys tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the API reference ( https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/invoices/#post-invoices ):

```
When can't an invoice be updated?
An invoice can't be updated if:

* it has been fully paid
* it has part-payments or credit notes applied to it
* it is in a locked period
```

So no, once it's fully paid you can't update it.